# How can I set an account lockout policy for the administrator account on rdp?

Tags: rdp, security

I'm following this page on security tips for RDP (for my online server):

http://www.mobydisk.com/techres/securing_remote_desktop.html

Now I don't have a special user account for RDP access. Just the administrator can log on. However, I want to make sure that someone can't brute force the password.

I've set the 'account lockout policy' to 3 attempts and a retry after 3 minutes. However, when I connect back with RDP I can still try 5 times before RDP breaks the connection. I can then immediately reconnect and try 5 more times.

Any ideas if there is a lockout policy which also holds true fro the admin?

Comment: Many people handle this by simpling renaming the Administrator account.  Yes it is a bit of obscurity-based-security, but it may help a little.  After you rename you could create a un-privileged account with the name administrator.

Comment: ok..so I create a new user and give admin rights and configure a proper lockout, and the real admin I just rename into something weird so it can't be guessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't want to setup a lockout policy for your only Admin user.**

Reason being: You create a major security hole in your setup as an attacker could prevent your access by simply continuously brute forcing against your admin access (a.k.a. The other side of account lock-out).

The best options are:

- Restrict RDP to specific IP sources;
- Rename the Administrator user

You don't list your Windows Version but here's how to do it on [Windows 2003 and 2008](http://faq.1and1.com/dedicated_servers/windows_server/windows_security/3.html).

***Note:*** You can also use [GPO to rename the account across multiple machines](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816109)

Comment: Your point about the denial of service could apply to any account, not just the built-in Administrator account, which really should not be used on a regular basis.

Comment: Sure thing... but the person would have to enumerate the username first, which on a system with only RDP exposed to external parties is not trival - except if you allow that cute "known users" feature to run via RDP.

The issue with Administrator/root (and to be fair with any other default account) is that you know exists and as such the brute forcing is easier.

This - the ability to enumerate valid users - is one of the reasons why login error messages should NOT differentiate between incorrect username or incorrect passwords (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/204.html)